# Understanding notation of indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

I have a hard time understanding some notation about an indicator function:
Let the measure space be given by

$ (\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu) $ and let $ \mu $ be the normal counting measure. Let $(f_n)_{1 \leq n}$ and  $(g_n)_{1 \leq n}$ be function defined in $\mathcal{M}^+$ and by:
$$f_n = 1_{\{ n \} } $$

$$
g_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1_{ \{ 1 \} } & \quad n \text{ is odd} \\
            1_{ \{ 2 \} } & \quad n \text{ is even}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
I want to find $ \limsup $ of both function, but I can't really understand what the notation of functions means.

To my knowledge $ 1_{A}(x)$ means that it is $1$ if it is in $A$ and $0$ otherwise, but that doesn't apply to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The indicator function $1_{\{2\}}$ is defined to be the function such that $f(2) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for any $x \ne 2$.

$$(f_n) = 1_{\{1\}}, 1_{\{2\}}, 1_{\{3\}}, 1_{\{4\}}, \ldots$$

$$(g_n) = 1_{\{1\}}, 1_{\{2\}}, 1_{\{1\}}, 1_{\{2\}}, \ldots$$

Comment: thanks, does that mean that the $g_n$ sequence is 1,1,0,0,0,0,0...?

Comment: No, $g_n$ is the sequence of functions $1_{\{1\}},1_{\{2\}},1_{\{1\}},1_{\{2\}},\ldots$.

Comment: @ViktorJeppesen arkeet is correct. $g_n$ is a sequence of functions.

Comment: ohhh of course, I somehow missed the point of it being a sequence of functions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I thought about it for an embarrassing long time, and I can't seem to find the lim sup of $g_n$. They are both defined on the extended real axis. Then lim sup $ (f_n) = I_{ \infty } $ (I think) but my intuition says that $limsup(g_n)=I_{ \{2 \} } $ but i'm not sure. Can you confirm

Comment: @VictorJeppensen I believe the limsup of $f_n$ is the zero function and the limsup for $g_n$ is $1_{\{1,2\}}$.

Comment: @ViktorJeppesen. Are you sure the functions are defined on the extended real axis and not $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @DenizSargun you are right. Thanks so much for your help